# Angular 12/Typescript/rxjs: error handling of nested Promises and rxjs Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a mix of nested Promises and subscriptions, and I simple want to do the following:

- Call my function bar() and understand if it was fully successfully, or if an error occurred

current approach:
Currently my bar() returns a boolean Observable, and I handle each error separately, for Promise via .catch, for the rxjs Observable via the error handle:

```js
    foo(): void {
       this.bar.subscribe((data: boolean) => console.log('the function call bar() was ' + data));
    }

    bar(): Observable<boolean> {
    let subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    
        this.httpHandler.newFoo().subscribe(
        (data) => 
          this.bar(data)
            .then((barData) => 
              this.httpHandler.updateBar().subscribe(
                (barData2) => subject.next(true),
                (error) => subject.next(false)))
            .catch(err => subject.next(false)),
        (error) => subject.next(false));

        return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

Apparently this is messy, and looks like an overkill for the simple purpose to understand if the bar() function call finished without any errors. Is there a better way to handle nested errors altogether?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be succinctly written as:

```
this.httpHandler.newFoo().pipe(
  switchMap(data =>
    from(this.bar(data)).pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        this.httpHandler.updateBar().pipe(
          mapTo(true)
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  catchError(() => of(false))
)
```

To make an observable out of a promise, use `from()`. Use `switchMap()` to transition between observables. Then it's just a matter of chaining your calls:

`this.httpHandler.newFoo()` -> `this.bar()` -> `this.httpHandler.updateBar()`

and returning `true` in the end, otherwise `false` for any error.

Comment: switchMap actually internally uses `from`, so you don’t need to use it. Also, it looks like you don’t need the nested pipes. So I think you could simplify to: `this.httpHandler.newFoo().pipe(switchMap(), switchMap(), mapTo(), catchError());`

Comment: @BizzyBob the nesting to me is a style choice, so there's clear divisions for the boundaries of the call or if I somehow needed the inputs for the response handler. That works too.